# Anonymous function in event listener vs anonymous function to function in event listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, anonymous-function

I have a variable p1Score that is a number and p1ScoreDisplay that is the content of a span. I made an event listener that adds 1 to the score every time it is clicked and updates the span using:

```
p1.addEventListener("click", function()
{   
p1Score++;
p1ScoreDisplay.textContent = p1Score;
});
```

This works correctly, however, I don't want to make the function anonymous. I created a separate function and made an anonymous function that goes to the function like so:

```
function addPoint(score, scoreDisplay)
{
score++;
scoreDisplay.textContent = score;
}

p1.addEventListener("click", function(){addPoint(p1Score,p1ScoreDisplay);});
```

This version only preforms the event once while the other one occurs every time and I am not sure why?

Comment: in reality, you compare two different approaches, one with a global variable, and the other with a handed over primitive and an object. if you take two objects, you could use the object for incrementing a property and use it in a different event as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you increment the value of `p1Score`. The next click increments it again.

In the second example, you copy the value of `p1Score` to `score`, then you increment the value of `score`. The next click copies the **original and unchanged** value of `p1Score` to `score` and increments it again.